# TensorFlow Batch Outer Product

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following two tensors:

```
x, with shape [U, N]
y, with shape [N, V]
```

I want to perform a batch outer product: I'd like to multiply each element in the first column of `x` by each element in the first row of `y` to get a tensor of shape `[U, V]`, then the second column of `x` by the second row of `y`, and so on. The shape of the final tensor should be `[N, U, V]`, where `N` is the batch size.

Is there any simple way to achieve this in TensorFlow? I've tried to use `batch_matmul()` without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would the following work, using [`tf.batch_matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#batch_matmul)?

```
print x.get_shape()  # ==> [U, N]
print y.get_shape()  # ==> [N, V]

x_transposed = tf.transpose(x)
print x_transposed.get_shape()  # ==> [N, U]

x_transposed_as_matrix_batch = tf.expand_dims(x_transposed, 2)
print x_transposed_as_matrix_batch.get_shape()  # ==> [N, U, 1]

y_as_matrix_batch = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)
print y_as_matrix_batch.get_shape()  # ==> [N, 1, V]

result = tf.batch_matmul(x_transposed_as_matrix_batch, y_as_matrix_batch)
print result.get_shape()  # ==> [N, U, V]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, there is a more elegant solution using [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum):

```py
result = tf.einsum("un,nv->nuv", x, y)
```