# Pairwise sum in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have two tensors `A` and `B`, both of shape `[10 5]`. How do I compute a tensor `C` of shape `[10 5 5]` such that `C[x, i, j] = A[x, i] + B[x, j]`?

Edit: this is the sum analog of outer-product, not the outer product itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow Batch Outer Product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213787/tensorflow-batch-outer-product)

Comment: The operation you are trying to compute is called outer-product, instead of pairwise sum. Googling for numpy and tensorflow outer product operationd already gives plenty of results.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo take another look, `A[x, i] + B[x, j]` would not be a product.

Comment: @Tadhg ops! Yob are right. I just had a quick read to the question, it is completely valid then :) I got distracted by the `matmul` in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly more readable and succinct than @user1735003's answer:

```
A[:, :, None] + B[:, None, :]
```

*(Actually, the other answer swapped the axes)*

Comment: I'm being just curious here: is that just numpy syntax, or it does also apply when `A` and `B` are tensors? In other words, does tensorflow support that notation?

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting).

```
op1 = tf.expand_dims(A, axis=2)
op2 = tf.expand_dims(B, axis=1)
C = tf.add(op1, op2)
```

Beware that the solution of @MaxB is not equivalent to this one as the operator `[]` is equivalent to a call to `strided_slice`, not `expand_dims`.

Comment: Do you think strided_slice is slower or takes more memory?

Comment: It could, in that expand_dim is a trivial op, unlike strided_slice.

Comment: I expect them to execute equivalently (If not, someone should submit a bug report)

Comment: I donnot see why this would be a bug. An optimization rather. In any case until proven equivalent I would go with the safer approach.

Comment: Well, you are the one saying "beware" without evidence. I would frankly be quite surprised if these had different performance characteristics when handling large arrays.

Comment: @MaxB Strange comment. You don't have any evidence that they behave the same either. And as I said, `expand_dims` is a trivial op, unlike `strided_slice`. As `expand_dims` cannot be less efficient, why not using it?

Comment: For the same reason we don't code in assembly and PTX

Comment: ... Just tried tf.reduce_sum(a[:, None, :], axis=2) vs tf.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), axis=2) . They run out of VRAM at exactly the same time, meaning that the former does not introduce any new copies.

Comment: @MaxB Well that is certainly a good sign, even though that quite doesn't nail it. Comparing using `expand_dims` to assembly is embarrassing though.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using the property `log(e^x * e^y) == x+y` to accomplish addition from the `matmul` operation:

```
op1 = tf.reshape(tf.exp(A), [10, -1, 1])
op2 = tf.reshape(tf.exp(B), [10, 1, -1])
C = tf.log(tf.matmul(op1, op2))
```

but I'm guessing there would be a simpler/faster way out as well.